# Almost sure convergence and convergence of expectations

Tags: probability-theory

Good evening,

I have a small doubt. I have a sequence $(D_t)_{t\geq 1}$ of non-negative random variables converging almost surely to a non-negative random variable $X$ with $E[X]<\infty$. I know that $E[D_t]$ converges to $1$. Is it possible to conclude that the limiting random variable $X$ is almost surely positive? If not, can you provide a counterexample? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $D_t := t 1_{(0,1/t)}$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure

Comment: Thanks Saz. It is clear that $E(D_t)$ converges to $1$. Concerning the almost sure convergence, you mean have that $D_t$ converges to $\infty \cdot 0=0$ for every $\omega$?

Comment: $D_t$ converges almost surely to $0$ on $(0,1)$. Note that for any $\omega \in (0,1)$ it holds that $D_t(\omega)=0$ for $t$ sufficiently large.